# Making an image float to the left of an HTML list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to float an image to the left of an HTML list. Well it seems possible, but can I make it look nice with the bullets not on top of the image? I need the bullets to line up with the text above and below the list.

Here's a [jsfiddle with a heading and list underneath](http://jsfiddle.net/gQZ3F/1/):

```
<img src="http://images.ucode.com/facebook.png"/>
<h1>A heading</h1>
<ul style="float: left">
    <li>a point</li>
    <li>another point</li>
    <li>third item</li>
    <li>trying to</li>
    <li>get past</li>
    <li>floating graphic</li>
</ul>
```

I love how the list flows around the image. Works great except the bullets for the list items that are to the right of the image should be aligned with the left side of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the [`list-style-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) is set to `outside` so make it `inside`

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gQZ3F/3/)

---

Though, there's a catch here, using `inside` is appropriate when dealing with single/multiple word list items which do not wrap, as the wrapped text will move below the bullet which you might not need, in that case, remove `list-style-position: inside;` and use `margin` on your `img` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to add position relative to the list and then give a left: value(ie 20px).
Just a minor addition to Mr Alien's great answer, adding a margin-right to the image will not only push the list but also text that might exist before or after it- the result might seem misaligned. 
Here's a fiddle with the relative position approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/egeo/zgf4un7d/1/

```
img {
    float: left;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is 1) it might brakes clickable elements (eg. links) in a right floating box and 2) items containing long text will overlap with this same box: https://jsfiddle.net/4de8to9z/1/

Answer (score 1):

A little padding to the right of the image should be ok?

```
img {
    float: left;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Padding is acceptable, but margin is safer way: imagine you would need  a border for the image?

Comment: padding doesn't work, it shifts the heading and other non-list text to the right as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Mr. Alien answered well. Another thing is to add margin/margin-right to `img`;

http://jsfiddle.net/gQZ3F/10/

Comment: padding doesn't work, it shifts the heading and other non-list text to the right as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added a wrapper to your ul which has float left

```
div.right {
float:left;
}
```

[take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/gQZ3F/12/)

Comment: Then the list doesn't flow around the image, just comes straight down.